# HTML Presentation Toolkit

Tags: html, presentation

I've seen HTML presentations like these four a lot :

1. http://estelle.github.com/mobileperf/
2. http://slides.html5rocks.com
3. http://html5apps-io2010.appspot.com
4. http://www.igvita.com/slides/2012/wordpress-performance/

I want to know the specific tool used to create such type of presentations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should give [landslide](https://github.com/adamzap/landslide) a try.

Comment: Thanks, though Im more interested in knowing how 
http://html5apps-io2010.appspot.com was developed.

Comment: I see a similar question has been posted here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2533908/basic-framework-for-presentations-using-html5-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You must try [HTLM5 pageforest](http://html5slides.pageforest.com/) for creating beautiful presentations with an instant slide preview alongside